# matplotlib.pyplot x-axis is nanosec even if index in pandas is datetime

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have a pandas data frame where the index is of type `pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex`. I have two columns `Mx` and `My`, and I want to plot it using matplotlib.

Code:

```
start=pd.Timestamp('2017-02-10 00:00')
stop=pd.Timestamp('2017-03-10 16:00')
plt.figure()
plt.plot(mydata[start:stop]['Mx'], label='Mx')
plt.plot(mydata[start:stop]['My'], label='My')
plt.title('Timeseries')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Angle [deg]')
plt.xlabel('UTC time')
plt.show()
```

For some reason, this works fine otherwise on my colleague's computers, but not mine. Any ideas on why it is like this?

[image: Time series x-axis is given in nanosecond, but I want to show actual dates]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I had matplotlib 2.0.0 installed. Upgraded to the latest (2.1.2) and it worked.